# How to give values to an array of integers within a structure?

Tags: arrays, debugging, pointers, integer, structure

I'm attempting to assign values to my integer array within a structure.  I wrote a small test program to demonstrate what I am trying to achieve.

```
typedef struct{
    int *alpha;
    int *beta;
} data_t;

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    int i=0;
    data_t data;
    for (i=0; i<100; i++){
        data.alpha[i] = i;
        data.beta[i] = i*i;
    }
    for (i=0; data.alpha[i]; i++){
        printf("Alpha = %d.\nBeta = %d.\n", data.alpha[i], data.beta[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

gdb tells me that the problem is in "data.alpha[i]=i", but I'm not sure how to assign this value correctly.  Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have any integer arrays, just two uninitialized pointers.

Try

```
typedef struct{
    int alpha[100];
    int beta[100];
} data_t;
```